# second table controller displaying 2 generic labels instead of instance properties

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, label

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u9rkvwsrcdoa7q8/AABwKm_djSB2oENzuJNT1u35a?dl=0

include above, is the last iteration of this simple project I'm working on.
I am super close to achieving the basic fundamentals I wanted to practice with this project.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble with the two cells with generic labels in the second table controller.

my first table controller displays these 4 restaurant types

```
 let restaurantTypesArray = ["American", "Burgers", "Chinese", "Italian"]
```

if i choose "american", i want the array holding instances of (american) restaurants to be passed to the second controller. There, I want to simply display the name properties of the selected restaurants in my table.

This is my current view, if i select American in the first table controller I am just left with generic labels, indicated the values of the instances within the array.
[image]

I simply want these two labels to display the names "McDonalds" & "Burger King".

Any thoughts or suggestions towards a solution?

Comment: did u connect the labels to the code ?

Comment: I'm using the same "type cell" for both the first and second table controller.

Comment: u need to send the data through prepareForSegue method

Comment: to solve my problem, i actually just created a second cell.  I guess the first was ill-configured!  Thank you for the suggestion!